# Oracle snippet does not give back results

Tags: java, io, nio

Here I have the following bit of code taken from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) oracle java tutorial:

```
// Defaults to READ
try (SeekableByteChannel sbc = Files.newByteChannel(file)) {
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);

    // Read the bytes with the proper encoding for this platform.  If
    // you skip this step, you might see something that looks like
    // Chinese characters when you expect Latin-style characters.
    String encoding = System.getProperty("file.encoding");
    while (sbc.read(buf) > 0) {
        buf.rewind();
        System.out.print(Charset.forName(encoding).decode(buf));
        buf.flip();//LINE X
    }
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.out.println("caught exception: " + x);
```

So basically I do not get any output out of it. 
I have tried to put some flags in the while loop to check whether or not it gets into, and it gets into. I also changed the encoding in `Charset.defaultCharset().decode(buf)`, result : no output. 
Of course there is text in the file passed to `newByteChannel(file);`

Any idea?
Thanks a lot in advance.

**

### EDIT:

** Solved, it was just the file I was trying to access that had been previously accidentally corrupted. After having changed file, everything is working.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks wrong. Try changing the `rewind()` to `flip(),` and the `flip()` to `compact().`

Comment: Then try removing the initial flip(). I seem to remember that decode() does that internally, and presents you with a flipped buffer. Don't lost the compact() though.

Comment: Ok sorry about that, apparently the file I was trying to access via channel was corrupted. That's why the oracle snippet did not work. Now that I recreated the file everything works fine with the original oracle code.

Comment: @EJP Do you think in this case it would be ok to use clear() instead of compact()? As far as I understand compact() handles the case that not all data was consumed, which probably is not the case with a CharsetDecoder.

Comment: @Joe23 I don't see any reason to even think about taking the risk. 'Probably' isn't strong enough for me.

Comment: @EJP Understood. I found this question looking for a discussion of the broken example in the oracle documentation mentioned by op. Was just trying to make sure my understanding of the API is correct. Thank you for taking the time to anwer.